# Python system resources enumeration

Tags: python, cpu, enumeration, ram

I'm trying to get system information. I have to avoid installing third-party packages and libraries or modules that require the latest version of python to run. This is still in early dev and currently only tested on Ubuntu 10.04 but I will play with that later. I'm having trouble with getting the proper information for memory usage.

So far what I have is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import platform
import multiprocessing
import os

print "\nEnumerating Available System Resources..."

print "\n++++++++++ OS Name and version ++++++++++"

print "Platform:", platform.system()
print "Kernel:", platform.release()
print "Distro:", platform.linux_distribution()
print "Architecture:", platform.architecture()

print "\n++++++++++ CPU Cores ++++++++++"
p = os.popen("ps aux|awk 'NR > 0{s +=$3};END{print s}'").read()
print "Cores:", multiprocessing.cpu_count(), '\nCPU Load:', p

print "\n++++++++++ System Memory ++++++++++\n"

def meminfo():
    meminfo=dict()

    with os.popen('cat /proc/meminfo') as f:
        for line in f:
            meminfo[line.split(':')[0]] = line.split(':')[1].strip()
    return meminfo

if __name__=='__main__':
    meminfo = meminfo()
    print('Total Memory: {0}'.format(meminfo['MemTotal']))
    print('Free Memory: {0}'.format(meminfo['MemFree']))
```

The problem is that the last portion I get the proper memory stats but I also need to add a "usage" portion in percentage format. I can't figure out how to get the math right, though.

I need this because some of the systems that I work on may be tapped out on ram and I can't allow the script to crash the machine so I will need to also add something in here to evaluate the RAM percentage and CPU percentage and not continue if certain conditions exist such as CPU load over 75% and RAM less than 5% remaining. I would like some insight to those functions, also but the primary concern right now is getting the memory usage percentage. I've been at this for hours and could use some fresh eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the `free` command instead?

```
import os
import re
def meminfo():

    with os.popen('free -m') as f:
        output = f.read()

    fields = re.search(r'Mem\:\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)',
            output,re.M).group
    return dict(total=fields(1),used=fields(2),free=fields(3),
            shared=fields(4),buffers=fields(5),cached=fields(6))

print meminfo()
```

Output:

```
{'used': '3292', 'buffers': '105', 'cached': '2063', 'shared': '0', 'total': '3550', 'free': '257'}
```

Note that the `-m` outputs everything in megabytes. You can use `-k` for kilobytes, `-g` for gigabytes, or just `free` by itself to output in bytes.

`free` should be available pretty much anywhere /proc/meminfo is.

As to your original question, to get the percentage in use you would use:

```
used/total
```

or

```
(total-free)/total
```

But note that this can be misleading on linux as the used value includes any cached files. So for a really accurate count of memory that is locked so to speak you would use:

```
(used-cached)/total
```

or

```
(total-free-cached)/total
```

Comment: This is not an answer to any of the questions I posted. I am not looking to use any other tools or *nix cmd. I am simply looking for an addition to my previous post. I only need how much ram is being used in percentage so that I can halt the script if it exceeds the threshold. It should be something like subtracting MemFree from MemTotal to get MemUsed and then converting that to a percentage.

Comment: I apologize if that sounded harsh. I just read it and didn't mean for it to sound that bad. The script I have has a clean output and I would like to keep it that way as some of the junior's will be using this script. It's the start of a compromised server investigation script to help speed things up. We have a lot of servers and can't install or remove packages/softwares from the systems. I appreciate the answer but it's not what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to answer the exact question. See my updated answer. The problem with your current code is that ```meminfo``` contains things like ```'1343434 kb'```, i.e. strings that can't be converted to ints directly.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hadn't thought of that. I still can't get it to return the percentage. I have been trying the method you provided. Where exactly am I supposed to put the (used-cached)/total ?

Comment: Let's say for instance you have ```used=100```, ```cached=100```, and ```total=400```. Then you could do something like ```percent = (used-cache)/total```. You could multiply the result by 100 to get scaled by 100 value (i.e. 0-100 instead of 0-1).